# Wifi range is cut down all of a sudden

Tags: wireless, 21.04

I am using Ubuntu 21.04. Everything was going good, but suddenly yesterday, I couldn't connect to my Wi-Fi. It will connect, but after some time, it will disconnect. When I am very close to the modem there is no problem, but when I am a little far away this issue starts.

I am using Windows alongside Ubuntu. I can use my Wi-Fi with Windows with no problem at a location, but can't use Wi-Fi with Ubuntu at the same location.

Results of `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`:

`32979391.8832] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds) 32979391.9433] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake 32979392.9476] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed 32979394.6441] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected 32979395.2368] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning 32979399.7789] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating 32979399.7811] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating 32979399.8008] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated 32979399.8008] device (wlo1): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested 32979399.8302] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction 32979399.8303] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> done`
The above output is repeated in the log.

Output of  lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Net' command is:
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821] DeviceName: WLAN    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]  Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, rtl8821ce 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c2)`

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thank you, But I don't know the meaning of any of the outputs. I'll paste it here.

Comment: What is the wireless device? Post `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Net'`

Comment: @Pilot6 I will check and will paste the result here. Thank you.

Comment: @Pilot6, please find the output above.